# What migration paths should we have?

Tags: discussion, migration

I recently found a question which belonged more on Open Data than here, and it got me started thinking about our migration paths.

Since they haven't been set up yet, we only have our Meta site as a migration option. However, we are already getting questions which need to be migrated out.

Instead of just making our poor, overworked (not really) mods do this, maybe we should start thinking about what paths we want for migration.

Format:

> *Site Name, using the `##` syntax:*
>
> ### Foo Stack Exchange
>
> *Site URL*:
>
> http://foo.stackexchange.com
>
> *Optional pitch*:
>
> We really need Foo because they can bar the baz we get.

Comment: Aren't migration options in the close options decided based on our migration history and listed automatically from the most frequent ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Migration options aren't an option for beta sites. When we graduate, we'll figure it out, if we need it. In the mean while, flag said questions for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently reviewing a question in the Space.SE close queue.  It was clearly a good candidate for migration, but the only option now available was to *this* meta site.

Acknowledging @PearsonArtPhoto's observation, when we have the ability to choose migration paths, my suggestions would be:

- Astronomy SE
- Earth Science SE
- Physics SE
- Space meta
- Worldbuilding SE

Less useful, but perhaps relevant:

- Biology SE
- Chemistry SE
- Medical Sciences SE